# Redirect https://www domain to https://non-www domain in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ssl, web, web-applications

I have around 50 domains on the Nginx server for which an SSL certificate(non-www SSL certificate) is issued.

Now, When we try to open a site like https://www[Domain], there is a 'common name' error as the certificate is not installed for www.

I want to redirect any https://www[domain] to https://[domain], I tried several solutions available on blogs, but it seems the below code only works when SSL is installed on a domain as I reissued www certificate for one of the domain then I can redirect using below code block. but we doesn't want to reissue certificates for all domains with www

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.[domain];    
    return 301 $scheme://[domain]$request_uri;
}
```

I also tried some regex with Server block but it also doesn't work

```
server { 
    server_name "www.(.+?\.\w+)" ; 
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri; 
}
```

How I can make this work?

Comment: You can't. `https` requires a valid certificate. If you do not have a valid certificate for `www.example.com`, the user's browser will complain.

Comment: In theory you can try to generate Let's Encrypt certificates for those domains on the fly with the [`lua-resty-auto-ssl`](https://github.com/auto-ssl/lua-resty-auto-ssl) module (you would need an [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) or [`lua-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) instead of "vanilla" nginx to do it). Otherwise I don't think it is possible.